# $.Ajax loading an HTML code and show it after like with JQuery .load

Tags: ajax, load, show

I have a question because i really don't understand ...
I have code two functions, one work, the other not, i really want to understand why please ...

When i do that :

```
$("#divLogin").load("./affichage/choixFormat.html", function() {
    $("#choix-box").fadeIn(300);
});
```

It works fine, it load the HTML in the DIV and after show it.

But i have code for me a best script with $.Ajax who don't work :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "./affichage/choixFormat.html",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        cache: true,
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function() {
        $("#loading").removeClass("hide");
        },
        timeout: 5000,
        error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(request.status);
        },
        success: function (msg, textStatus, request) {
        $("#divLogin").html(msg);
        }
    });
$("#choix-box").fadeIn(300);
```

The javascript try to fade the DIV before it finish to load i think ...
But i don't understand why ... i have select async:false !
And i fade after the success !

I prefer use $.Ajax because we can make more things with it ...
Who can esplain me why it doesn't working ?
And the JQuery .load is working fine :(

Thanks

---

I'm wrong sorry the two solution doesn't works :(
I must load two time the DivLogin for fadeIn it :(

I also try to do :

```
request.done(function(msg) {
    console.log("End of div loading");
    $("#choix-box").fadeIn(300);
});
```

But it doesn't work too :(
I only have the LOG in the console.
The DOM is too long to load the HTML and can't show it ... it is why i must load it a first time, and at the second time the script is executed.

Who have an other solution please ?

---

Now i try too many things ... the best for the moment is :

```
$('#div').ready( $("#div").fadeIn(300) );
```

But it is not always perfect too :(
Really no real solution in JQuery please ?

---

Ok here my last code who not always show my div :(
Some time yes, and some time no, impossible to understand why ?

```
$('body').prepend('<div id="divChoiceFormat"></div>');
//getContenu('./affichage/choixFormat.html', 'divChoixFormat');

// CSS Load
appendCss("./style/choiceFormat.css", "choiceFormatCSS")

$("#divChoiceFormat").load("./affichage/choiceFormat.html", function() {

    // When ready
    $('#divChoiceFormat').ready( $("#choice-box").fadeIn(300) );
}
```

To load CSS before HTML i made :

```
function appendCss(url, id) {

    var link = $("<link>");
    link.attr({
        charset: "UTF-8",
        media:   "all",
        type:    'text/css',
        rel:     'stylesheet',
        id:      id,
        href:    url
    });
    $("head").append( link );

return false;
}
```

Maybe my order is false ?

Comment: If you use an id as selector, this must be uniq id in your entire HTML... if you have multiple id="#choix-box", your script doesnt work properly.
And dont use an ajax call for html ... .load() is enought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// before sent

// call
$("#divLogin").load("./affichage/choixFormat.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {

    if ( status == "error" ) {
        console.log('Error : '+ xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);

    }else if(status == "success"){
        $("#divLogin").html(response);
        $("#choix-box").fadeIn(300);

    }else if(status == "notmodified"){
        console.log('Error : similar html detected'); 

    }else{
        console.log('Error : no status'); 
    }
});
```

Thats obliviously works.
If it doesnt, there is other thing in your html.

- Check Ids if they are uniq for all blocks, else use a class for
  multiples calls with multiple blocks.
- Check your relative path too:'./affichage/choixFormat.html'
- Finally, cache the response in an instance to repeat load()
  efficently.
- And please, dont use Html in a ajax call... worst practice ever.

Answer (score 0):

Place this `$("#choix-box").fadeIn(300);` inside the ajax success.

```
success: function (msg, textStatus, request) {
        $("#divLogin").html(msg);
        $("#choix-box").fadeIn(300);
}
```

Comment: Have you an other solution please ...
I think i don't have really understand to know how an Ajax command is finised to work on the result !

Comment: `$("#loading").addClass("hide");` should also be added to you success function.  Beyond that, I think we need to see your `HTML`.

Comment: I have add in first post my code.
I create an div in DOM
Load the CSS
Load the HTML in the Div
Show the div

But some time the div is here, i can see it in the DOM with chromedebug but it is hidden like on the CSS, the show doesn't work !